# Spring MVC REST JSON HTTP 403

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

According to doc

http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html

have hext method

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/pets", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json")
public void addPet(@RequestBody Pet pet, Model model) {
    // implementation omitted
}
```

Also have an spring sec with next

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/pets").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }
```

Send request by POST plugin, like

```
Content-Type: application/json
{"email":"test@gamil.com","pass":"testpass"}
```

Have got an error

```
**Status:
403: Forbidden**


Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block

Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
```

What is wrong ?

Comment: Is `{"email":"test@gamil.com","pass":"testpass"}` suppose to be user credentials?

Comment: according to the rule of spring security `antMatchers("/pets").permitAll()` I can use this url without user credential. Yes ?

Comment: Yes..But by default `CSRF Protection` is enabled for `POST` requests. So you should either provide one or disable the `CSRF Protection`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/34703521/1393484

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Security Blocking public rest service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34702424/spring-security-blocking-public-rest-service)

Answer (score 0):

The following configuration only disables authentication and not `csrf` protection for your application, in order to fix that like others have suggested in the comments, you have to disable `csrf` for the specified endpoints or totally disable the `csrf` protection:

```
// Disable for pets endpoint only
http
    .csrf()
    .ignoringAntMatchers("/pets");

// Disable everywhere
http
    .csrf()
    .disable();
```

Alternatively if you do require `csrf` protection on some of your endpoints, you will have to add an additional method to get the actual token value:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/token", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getToken(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return ((CsrfToken) request.getAttribute("_csrf")).getToken();
}
```

After getting the actual token value you will have to append it in all of you requests using `X-CSRF-TOKEN` header.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. tried two options. It works 
1. 
`http          .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/reg").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .and().csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/pets")
                .and()
                .httpBasic();`

2. `http.csrf().disable()
               .authorizeRequests()
               .antMatchers("/reg").permitAll()
               .anyRequest().authenticated()
               .and()
               .formLogin()
               .and()
               .httpBasic();`

In my vision the first approach more appropriate, because it did not disable csrf. What do you think is it ok - disable csrf ?